# removing rectangle with mousepressed() processing

Tags: processing

At the moment my object changes when i click anywhere in the window.
But i just wanna change the object when i click on the object.
I have no clue how to do this, can someone help me with this?

```java
int a = 300,b = 200,c = 200,d = 100;

void setup()
{
size(600, 400);
background(230);
}

void draw(){

if (mousePressed == true) {
background(230);
ellipseMode(CENTER);
ellipse(300,200,200,100);
 a = 0;
 b = 0;
 c = 0;
 d = 0;

}

stroke(0);
fill(#032EFF);
rectMode(CENTER);
rect(a,b,c,d);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpful Forum posts and got it :)

Here is the working code:

```java
float a = 200;
float b = 150;
float c = 200;
float d = 100;

void setup()
{
size(600, 400);
background(230);
}

void draw(){
stroke(0);
fill(#032EFF);
rect(a,b,c,d);

if (mousePressed) {
 if(mouseX>a && mouseX <a+c && mouseY>b && mouseY <b+d){
   println("es hat funktioniert");
background(230);
ellipseMode(CENTER);
ellipse(300,200,200,100);
 a = 0;
 b = 0;
 c = 0;
 d = 0;
 }
 }
 }
```